# Ubuntu closes all the applications when lid is closed or suspended

Tags: linux, ubuntu, process, suspend, application

I have been facing this issue for a while now.

Every time I close my lid, my Ubuntu 21.10 closes all the applications that were open before I closed the lid.

Comment: Please add details: What does the syslog say?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.